# Gson fromJson deserialize

Tags: java, json, gson

I have the following json:

```
[
    {
        "": "",
        "substituted_restday": "2020-02-01",
        "original_restday": "2020-02-08",
        "id": "15d13f70-c0a852c0-3a925f13-6dca1982",
        "_UNIQUEKEY_": "15d1592a-c0a852c0-3a925f13b7c65023",
        "parentId": ""
    }, 
    {
        "": "",
        "substituted_restday": "2020-02-03",
        "original_restday": "2020-02-09",
        "id": "15d14d55-c0a852c0-3a925f13-727b70af",
        "_UNIQUEKEY_": "15d1592a-c0a852c0-3a925f13-3711a584",
        "parentId": ""
    }
]
```

I want to get the value of "substituted_restday" and "original_restday" from the JSON. So I used gson.from with the following syntax to concert it into JAVA object.

```
String[] str = gson.fromJson(JSON, String[].class);
```

However, it showed the following error:

```
com.google.gson.JsonParseException: The JsonDeserializer StringTypeAdapter failed to deserialize json object {"":"","substituted_restday":"2020-02-01","original_restday":"2020-02-08","id":"15d13f70-c0a852c0-3a925f13-6dca1982","_UNIQUEKEY_":"15d1592a-c0a852c0-3a925f13-b7c65023","parentId":""} given the type class java.lang.String
```

So, how can I get the value of "substituted_restday" and "original_restday" from the JSON? Thank you?

Answer (score 0):

#### Tree Structure

Gson can parse the JSON into a tree structure, similar to how XML can be parsed into a DOM tree. The nodes of the tree can be one of these subclasses of `JsonElement`: `JsonObject`, `JsonArray`, `JsonPrimitive`, and `JsonNull`.

Since the JSON starts with a `[`, you can parse into a `JsonArray`, like this:

```
JsonArray root = gson.fromJson(JSON, JsonArray.class);
for (JsonElement elem : root) {
    JsonObject obj = elem.getAsJsonObject();
    String substituted_restday = obj.get("substituted_restday").getAsString();
    String original_restday = obj.get("original_restday").getAsString();
    System.out.printf("substituted_restday = '%s', original_restday = '%s'%n",
                      substituted_restday, original_restday);
}
```

---

#### List of Maps

Gson can parse the JSON objects into a `Map`.

```
List<Map<String, String>> root = gson.fromJson(JSON, new TypeToken<List<Map<String, String>>>() {}.getType());
for (Map<String, String> obj : root) {
    String substituted_restday = obj.get("substituted_restday");
    String original_restday = obj.get("original_restday");
    System.out.printf("substituted_restday = '%s', original_restday = '%s'%n",
                      substituted_restday, original_restday);
}
```

---

#### Array of POJOs

Gson can parse the JSON objects into POJOs. This is the most type-safe way to handle the data.

```
MyObj[] root = gson.fromJson(JSON, MyObj[].class);
for (MyObj obj : root) {
    System.out.printf("substituted_restday = '%s', original_restday = '%s'%n",
                      obj.substitutedRestday, obj.originalRestday);
}
```

```
class MyObj {
    @SerializedName("")
    String blank;
    @SerializedName("substituted_restday")
    String substitutedRestday;
    @SerializedName("original_restday")
    String originalRestday;
    @SerializedName("id")
    String id;
    @SerializedName("_UNIQUEKEY_")
    String uniqueKey;
    @SerializedName("parentId")
    String parentId;
}
```

You would likely want getter and setter methods on your POJO. This is just a simplified running example.

---

*Output (from all 3)*

```
substituted_restday = '2020-02-01', original_restday = '2020-02-08'
substituted_restday = '2020-02-03', original_restday = '2020-02-09'
```

Comment: I tried to use List of map method. But it got "Encountered: <", do you know why?

Comment: @kaholee Without seeing what you did, I've not idea. If you need help, create a new question.

Answer (score -1):

```
JsonObject jsonObject = gson.fromJson( JSON, JsonObject.class);
```

then

```
jsonObject.get(substituted_restday); // returns a JsonElement for that name
jsonObject.get(original_restday);
```

Imo, you should create a pojo for the json element and then have fromJson method return an array of that pojo's. This link should give you more details - https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/gson-parse-json-array/

Comment: `com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonArray`